# php files inclusion structure in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, structure

I am currently experimenting with Joomla (3.7) templating system for my company. I am not new in php and inclusion, but a beginner with Joomla.

I have been searching through the web and i haven't found any clear structure schema for the file inclusion in Joomla, something like what we can find here for wordpress for example: https://codex.wordpress.org/File:Template_Hierarchy_2015.png

For example, i stumbled upon this: while experimenting with template creation, i wanted to store a value that could be used in a layout, testing `setUserState` function. The layout i tested was the one used to render custom fields (which are new in 3.7). The result is that it seems that `fields/render.php` is actually executed before template's `index.php` (the value is only available after page reload when set in index.php, whereas it is immediate when set in render.php).

Did someone saw a clear schema of this inclusion structure? It is not only for the said example, but mostly for a better understanding of the framework.. sorry if already asken or if too vague for the site.

**edit - note about my example:** collecting info bits by bits, it seems that the template file `index.php` is executed first and buffered so that it can be parsed for jdoc statements. Intuitively, because an article content is in this case imported by a jdoc (`<jdoc:include type="component" />`, the main content in the article page), the custom fields `render.php` should be called after index.php. Could it be the buffering part that prevents the user state to be set in time?